# How to take the sum when '+' is present?

Tags: python, string, stack, postfix-notation

I'm working with post-fix notation and stacks, and I'm wondering if/how I can sum the elements of a list, stack etc. when the string '+' is present?

For the example, I'm just going to use a list instead of a stack (although if you have a solution for the stack, by all means go ahead).

So, maybe if I had:

```
string = '1 2 3 +'
```

and turned this into a list:

```
['1','2','3','+']
```

if correct would evaluate to:

```
6
```

Here's what I had thought would work (Note: **The valid() function I made checks if it can be changed into a float based off the string. It's working fine**):

```
def post_fix(string):
     lst = []
     for i in string:
         if '(' in lst:
             pass
         elif valid(i) is True:      
             int(i)
             lst.append(i)
         elif '+' in string:
             '+' == sum(lst)
             print(sum(lst))

  post_fix('1 2 3 +')
```

How could I get this working so that if '+' or '-' etc. is present, it will do the appropriate operation?

**Note:** For simplicity, you can just assume that the operator will always be at the end. So don't worry about something like '12+34*', although if you have a solution for this, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: How do you plan to deal with 3 numbers when `+` is supposedly a binary operator?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You evaluate postfix notation using a stack. When you see a number, you push it onto the stack. When you see an operator, you pop off enough numbers to satisfy it and push the result. At the end, the stack should have only one item and you print it.

Now usually `+` is a binary operator: it takes two operands. In your case you want it to consume whatever is on the stack. That's an unconventional meaning for `+`, but it's simple enough to implement.

```
def postfix(tokens):
    stack = []
    tokens = tokens.split() if isinstance(tokens, str) else tokens
    for token in tokens:
        if token.isdigit() or token.startswith("-") and token[1:].isdigit():
            stack.append(int(token))
        elif token == "+":
            assert stack    # need at least one item
            result = 0
            while stack:
               result += stack.pop()
            stack.append(result)
        else:
            raise ValueError("invalid token {}".format(token))
    assert len(stack) == 1
    return stack[0]

print(postfix("1 2 3 +"))
```

This structure is easily extended to handle other operations. For example, you could use `+` for binary addition and `++` for sum all.

```
elif token == "++":   # sum all
    result = 0
    while stack:
       result += stack.pop()
    stack.append(result)
elif token == "+":    # binary additon
    stack.append(stack.pop() + stack.pop())
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several issues here. The first is `int(i)`. This doesn't creates a copy of `i` as an integer but doesn't modify `i` at all. The `i` you append to the list is still a string. The second issue is that this doesn't work for two digit numbers - you immediately append to the list instead of keeping track of possible two digit numbers.

Fixing these issues:

```
def valid(i):
  return i.isdigit()

def post_fix(string):
  lst = [0]
  for i in string:
    if i == '(':
      continue
    elif i == ' ':
      lst.append(0)
    elif valid(i):      
      lst[-1] *= 10
      lst[-1] += int(i)
    elif i == '+':
      print(sum(lst))

post_fix('1 2 3 +')
```

Output:

```
6
```

Answer (score 1):

Try doing this:

```
mystr = "1 2 3 4 +"
mylst = mystr.split() #converts the string to list:  ['1', '2', '3', '+']
nums = [ int(i) for i in mylst[:-1]] #list of numbers

if mylst[-1] == "+":  #check for the sign present at the end of the string/list
  print(sum(nums))

nums2 = ['1', '2', '3', '4']
print(sum(nums2))
```

If the sign is not at the end, try converting str to int using following list comprehension method:

```
nums = [ int(i) for i in mylst if i in "1234567890"]
```

This will prevent ValueError while converting elements to int for further calculations

Answer (score 0):

```
the_list = ['1','2','3','+'] 
if '+' in the_list:
    #do things related to it being present
```

I believe that you don't even need to convert it to a list (although it may make subsequent processing of numbers easier). Something like:

```
if '+' in '1 2 3 +':
```

should execute as well, because strings are treated as iterables in pyton

Answer (score 0):

```
lst = string.split()
if '+' in lst:
    # Do addition
elif '-' in lst:
    # Do subtraction
```

Comment: @LAD Thanks, I will try to improve future answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can't just take the sum, as the list is in string format, and "+" will always be a string, so:

```
if "+" in lst:
    total = sum([int(i) for i in lst if not i == "+"])
```

As a function:

```
def sum_list(x):
    if "+" in x:
        total = sum([int(i) for i in x if not i == "+"])
    return total
```

Answer (score 0):

Doing the following should work for the case of addition(+) being the last value of your string. You can add additional conditions to the post_fix method then for -, *, % etc:

```
def post_fix(string):
    result = None
    split_string = string.split()
    if '+' == split_string[-1]:
        result = sum(map(int, filter(lambda x: x.isdigit(), split_string)))
    return result
```

Just to breakdown this line in case its unclear:

```
filtered_digits = filter(lambda x: x.isdigit(), split_string)  # Checks if the string is a digit and adds it to the filtered_digits list
casted_to_int = map(int, filtered_digits)  # Casts all values found to be str representation of ints to int through the map function
result = sum(casted_to_int)  # sums our list of integers
```